# Do Open Source Package of Kendo UI supports Kendo charts/graph

Tags: kendo-ui

I just started with Kendo UI and I am using Open Source package of Kendo UI. SO in the package I am not able to see any javascript files which contains name chart. I want to display some charts . So I am doubt that is open source package of kendo ui is supporting charts.

Anyway I have added following Kendo.core.min.js and Kendo.data.min.js to the page and called to chart function. But it's throwing error.

Any guidance would be very really helpful .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Charts are not contained in the open source version of **Kendo UI Core** product. They are available in the professional version but this has a cost associated with it ($699). If you take a look at the following link: 
[Kendo UI Core vs Kendo UI Professional](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-ui/comparison)

If you require charting needs and do not wish to page for the Chart features then give [HighCharts](http://www.highcharts.com/) a look. They are free to use in a **non-commercial setting** and are generally considered one of the the better solutions out there.

Hopefully this answers your question adequately.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below URL , It will help you to find out which all features are available in which all versions.

https://github.com/telerik/kendo-ui-core

Answer (score 0):

There are too many open source, jquery based charts are available. See this list: http://socialcompare.com/en/comparison/javascript-graphs-and-charts-libraries